# Illuminated vs non luminous

Tags: terminology

Can illuminated be used in place of non luminous everytime? Like can air or glass ,which are see through materials, be said to be "illuminated".

Illuminated means lit up.
Non luminous means something that doesn't emit light.

So is it appropriate to say that all non luminous objects are illuminated

I got this query at a physics website which used the term illuminated objects in place of non luminous objects. I felt that this question was best posted under english.

Thanks

Comment: Your logic escapes me.

Comment: I was asking which classification is more appropriate luminous/non luminous or luminous/illuminated

Comment: No, not all non luminous objects are illuminated. Only objects that are exposed to a light source are illuminated by it.

Comment: If I have a non-luminous object in a darkened room is it illuminated?

Comment: Ikr thats why i had a doubt regarding luminous/illuminated classification

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> is it appropriate to say that all non luminous objects are illuminated

No. Objects can only be said to be illuminated if there is light shining on them.

If a non luminous item is in complete darkness then it is not illuminated.

> can air or glass ,which are see through materials, be said to be "illuminated".

Yes they can if light is shining on them. That is what illuminated means.

Comment: I don't think transparent objects can be illuminated.

Comment: Thanks. But is it ok to consider something we cannot see (like air) to be illuminated if it is exposed to light

Comment: @user194517 Literally, no. Illumination requires the reflection of light. Light is mostly transparent. But you can say “the dawn sky was illuminated by the rays of the breaking Sun”, understanding the illumination of glow we’re talking about is due to the *stuff* in the sky, like clouds and such. Metaphorically, well.. the rules for metaphors is “if they bought it, you sold it”.

Comment: michael hor. The OP cites air and glass. Glass can certainly be illuminated. Otherwise we wouldn't be able to see anything made of glass. Water has a slight blue color